# T-SQL select distinct based on highest values from another column

Tags: t-sql

I have a table that contains number of `tryouts`, `customerID`, `status` of that one tryout and some other columns with various data.

Of course a single `customerID` can have multiple number of `tryouts` ( in the real table first tryout is number 1, second one number 2 etc.).

Ex.

> - Customer ID = 1, tryout = 1
> - Customer ID = 1, tryout = 2
> - Customer ID = 1, tryout = 3
> - Customer ID = 2, tryout = 1
> - Customer ID = 3, tryout = 1
> - Customer ID = 3, tryout = 2

And I want to have all distinct `customerIDs` but for each one only the row, that contains the highest `tryout` number for each customer in one table with data from all the other columns as well.
Ex.
`tryouts`, `customerID`, `status`, `data1`, `data2`

How can I achieve that ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you only want the customer ID and tryout value then you can try the following:

```
SELECT customerID, MAX(tryout) AS max_tryout
FROM yourTable
GROUP BY customerID
```

If you want the entire record, then one option would be to use `ROW_NUMBER()`:

```
SELECT t.customerID, t.tryout, t.status, t.data1, t.data2
FROM
(
    SELECT *, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY customerID ORDER BY tryout DESC) rn
) t
WHERE t.rn = 1
```

Comment: Thank you. What about a case, if I want to have data from all columns as well, but my condition for tryouts and customer ID persists ?  Ex. tryouts, customerID, status, data1, data2

Comment: @NihilisticWonder My second query addresses this.  Reload your page.

Comment: I was a bit early...this returns only values that I define in the where clause. Is the a way to define something like where = max (column name) ?

Comment: I don't understand your comment.  Please update your question showing what output you have in mind.

Comment: Edited last two sentences

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
SELECT
    CustomerID,
    MAX(tryout) AS [Max tryout]
FROM
    TheTable
GROUP BY
   CustomerID
```

This should give you what you want